# Firebase functions not waiting for asynchronous code even with await

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a firebase function that writes a file to firebase storage:

```js
var tempJSONObject = {
  testing: "why are we testing",
  anothertest: "constanttesting"
}
try {
  const fileName = `storedjokes/81.json`
  const file = bucket.file(fileName);
  console.log('created file');
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(JSON.stringify(file));
  console.log('created write stream');
  var stringy = JSON.stringify(tempJSONObject);
  console.log("stringy created");
  await writeStream.write(stringy, (err) => {
    console.log("writing started");
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    } else {
      console.log("data written");
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error', e);
}
console.log('post write');
```

The code execution is fine but the console prints

> post write

and never prints

> writting started

why is the .write() statement not executing properly, and how is it possible for the code after it to execute before it has finished?

Comment: `writeStream.write` doesn't return a promise, so await doesn't do anything to pause the code.

Comment: How would I pause it then?

Comment: If that's your actual question here, then I suggest editing the question to better explain what your goal is.  Strictly speaking, I've already answered your question about why the write isn't working the way you expect. I also suggest showing the entire function and not just lines of code inside it.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the function call around a promise:

```js
var tempJSONObject = {
  testing: "why are we testing",
  anothertest: "constanttesting"
}
try {
  const fileName = `storedjokes/81.json`
  const file = bucket.file(fileName);
  console.log('created file');
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(JSON.stringify(file));
  console.log('created write stream');
  var stringy = JSON.stringify(tempJSONObject);
  console.log("stringy created");
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    writeStream.write(stringy, (err) => {
      console.log("writing started");
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      } else {
        console.log("data written");
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log('error', e);
}
console.log('post write');
```